# Replace values within object, issue preserving object structure

Tags: r

I am trying to run a factor analysis, and replace all loading values <=.3 with NA. When I run my code below to replace values the output I get back is a giant list, rather then the matrix I expected:

```
#Example using @Hack-R code
#install.packages("pacman")
require(pacman)
pacman::p_load(psych)

#using the Harman 24 mental tests,a built-in dataset
res <- fa(Harman74.cor$cov,4,rotate="promax", SMC=FALSE, fm="minres") #unweighted least squares is minres

#round output (For rounded output, the print.psych function defaults to 2 digits)
#roundedVals <- print.psych(res)

#write to CSV
write.csv(res$Structure,"fa_all_rounded_promax.csv",row.names=T)
```

This returns a matrix. How would I replace all values <=.3 with NA in this matrix?

I tried:

```
roundedVals[(is.numeric(res$Structure) & res$Structure<.3)]<-NA
```

but that didnt return a matrix (which is my goal) though it did replace values.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(pacman)
pacman::p_load(psych)

#using the Harman 24 mental tests,a built-in dataset
res   <- fa(Harman74.cor$cov,4,rotate="promax", SMC=FALSE, fm="minres") 

struc  <- as.matrix(res$Structure)

struc2 <- ifelse(struc < 0.3, NA, struc)

#write to CSV
write.csv(struc2,"fa_all_rounded_promax.csv",row.names=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort....I wasnt quite sure how to include a reproducible example for R. I added some details to my post (borrowing some of your code) to make my question more clear.

Comment: @Rilcon42 Ah, okay, great I think I can give you a better answer now